# PHP PDO - Using an array for a SELECT SQL Statement

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

I'm having a bit of an issue. Basically what I am trying to do is the following;

- I am using PDO
- I want the ability to pass an array containing the column name in the db (the key) and the info I want to insert (value). The array may contain 1, or many fields that need to be updated.
- I have designed a function that looks like this:

Sample Array being passed:

```
$columnsToRetrieve = array('column1' => 'info', 
                            'column2' => 'data', 
                            'column3' => 'data');
```

And a sample function (did not include the DB initialization part)

```
function updateInfo ($columnsToRetrieve, $whereClauseValue) {

    $counter = 1;
    $queryString = 'UPDATE table SET ';
    foreach ($columnsToRetrieve as $k => $V) {
        $queryString .= $k . ' = ?';    
    }
    $queryString .= 'WHERE column4 = ?'
    $stmt = $dbc->dbConnection->prepare($queryString);
    foreach ($columnsToRetrieve as $k => $v) {
        $stmt->bindParam($counter, $v);
        $counter++;
    }
    $stmt->bindParam($counter, $whereClauseValue);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

The problem is with the second foreach, where I am trying to use the bindParam($counter, $value). Although the right number and value populates, it doesn't seem to want to accept it.

Does anyone have any ideas how this can be done, or what I'm doing wrong above?

Comment: "it doesn't seem to want to accept it."  Can you be more specific?

Comment: You do know with PDO you can do `->execute( array(....) );` dont you? And therefore you can loose the `bindParam()`

Comment: Maybe you should read this https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

Comment: And in your query you need `,` after each `?` and a space before `WHERE`. But who outputs variables now, pfffff.

Comment: A simple `echo $queryString;` should show you a few obvious errors

Comment: i wrote this quickly at work, even with the , it still happens. i said originally the code was just a quick sample. the problem isnt with the query its with how i'm trying to bind the parameters

Comment: also @RiggsFolly, i'm trying to review that documentation you provided but I don't really see a section that illustrates how to do what I want.

Comment: Click on `binding methods` and look at the first code example

Comment: @RiggsFolly, that was what I was originally looking at, but I feel like it's not what I'm trying to do. In the example there, I feel like that is for when you have mulitple rows to update.. For me I only want to update 1 row and the columns which are going to be updated is in the array. In that example, they are still hardcoding the columns into the query.

Answer (score 1):

After debugging your code I see two issues:

1. missing semicolon after `$queryString .= 'WHERE column4 = ?'` part.
2. If I dump your resulting query, it would be something like

`UPDATE table SET column1 = ?column2 = ?column3 = ?WHERE column4 = ?`

see missing spaces. So what if you modify this line:

```
$queryString .= $k . ' = ?';
```

to

```
$queryString .= $k . ' = ?,';
```

and (in order to strip the last comma)

```
 $queryString .= ' WHERE column4 = ?'
```

replace with

```
$queryString = substr($queryString,0,-1) .  ' WHERE column4 = ?';
```

Comment: thanks for pointing that out.. i just quickly wrote this an know theres a few errors in the query string, but even if the string is correct it still has the problem

Answer (score 1):

95% sure that your issue is your use of `bindParam`.  `bindParam` works by reference, not by value.  As a result your foreach loop isn't binding your **values** to your query, but rather the `$v` variable.  By the time you call execute all parameters are bound to the same `$v` variable, so when you execute your query does not behave as expected.

The solution is simple: use [`bindValue()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) or [`execute()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php).  Personally, I use `execute()` exclusively: it is simple to understand and read.  Without a doubt though, the reference nature of `bindParam()` will cause plenty of trouble: I've been burned by it before.

**Edit to add specific example**

I've copied and pasted your above code, so any errors will remain here, but it is actually much simpler with `execute()`

```
function updateInfo ($columnsToRetrieve, $whereClauseValue) {

    $counter = 1;
    $queryString = 'UPDATE table SET ';
    foreach ($columnsToRetrieve as $k => $V) {
        $queryString .= $k . ' = ?';    
    }
    $queryString .= 'WHERE column4 = ?'
    $stmt = $dbc->dbConnection->prepare($queryString);

    $values = array_values( $columnsToRetrieve );
    $values[] = $whereClauseValue();

    $stmt->execute( $values );
}
```

Comment: Hey Conor, appreciated the input. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With the assistance of @RiggsFolly and @Sebastian Brosch, I was able to better understand the scenario. I looked up some past posts as well, and was able to tailor a possible solution:

```
$columnsToRetrieve = array('name' => 'Frank', 'phone' => '1112223333');
$email = 't@t.com';

$values = array();

$string = 'UPDATE users SET';

foreach ($columnsToRetrieve as $k => $v) {
    $string .= ' ' . $k . ' = :' . $k . ',';
    $values[':' . $k] = $v;
};

$string = substr($string, 0, -1);

$string .= ' WHERE email = :email;';

$values[':email'] = $email;

try {
    $stmt = $dbc->prepare($string);
    $stmt->execute($values);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: One mistake: you need the colon before the name of your placeholder in your sql query, but when you build your array you want to just use the placeholder name as the key: you don't include the colon in the keys of the array that gets passed to execute.  I.e.: `$values['email'] = $email` and `$values[$k] = $v;`.  In this case though, I would say that using positional arguments is easier.  Either way, you've ditched the bindParam that was causing the original bug, so this will work.

Comment: Thanks for the input again Conor.. I actually was able to successfully run the above code without error. Do you mind explaining a bit more what it looks like I've done wrong?

Comment: After a little more digging I realized what is going on, which is that nothing is wrong.  The PHP documentation shows using a colon in the array key name.  However, this colon is not actually required.  In actual use I have only seen it executed without the colon, so I presumed that the version with the colon was a mistake.  Turns out either one works.  You learn something new every day!

Comment: Awesome. Appreciate the input though. So im guessing you were referenced to the $values[':' $key] part?

Comment: Yes.  `$values[':' . $k] = $v;` becomes `$values[$k] = $v;`.